# Как запуск php скрипта с отвязкой от консоли?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт с бесконечным циклом.
Как запуск его из консоли (с какими параметрами, или методом) с отвязкой от консоли, чтобы при закрытии консоли - соединения от сервера, скрипт продолжил выполняться?

Comment: `php file.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

Comment: ```nohup php /path/to/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &```